# Как реализовать простую очередь в NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-faq

Допустим, у нас есть 10 задач, которые нужно выполнить параллельно, но оперативной памяти (`os.freemem()`) хватает только на 7. Можно ли как-то поставить выполняться 7 задач, но чтобы остальные ждали своей очереди и запускались только когда появляется свободная для выполнения память?

Comment: Можно взять например https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallelLimit

Answer (score 3):

Функция для запуска задач в указанном количестве:

```
function sequence(ts, limit) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var res = [];
    var index = 0, done = 0;

    function go() {
      var i = index++;

      ts[i] && ts[i]().then(
        result => res[i] = {result},
        error => res[i] = {error}
      ).finally(
        () => {
          if (++done === ts.length) {
            resolve(res);
          } else {
            go();
          }
        }
      )
    }

    for (var q=0; q<limit; ++q) {
      go()
    }
  });
}
```

Пример использования:

```
async function showAll(ids) {
  var res = await sequence(ids.map(id => () => getItem(url, id)), 10);

  document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = res.map(({result, error}) => `
    <div style="background:${error ? 'red' : 'green'}">${escapeHTML(error || result)}</div>
  `).join("");
}
```

Источник: https://vk.com/wall-102547801_290

Запускаемый пример:

```js
function sequence(ts, limit) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var res = [];
    var index = 0, done = 0;

    function go() {
      var i = index++;

      ts[i] && ts[i]().then(
        result => res[i] = {result},
        error => res[i] = {error}
      ).finally(
        () => {
          if (++done === ts.length) {
            resolve(res);
          } else {
            go();
          }
        }
      )
    }

    for (var q=0; q<limit; ++q) {
      go()
    }
  });
}

var escapeHTML = (function () {
  var div = document.createElement('div');

  return function escapeHTML(text) {
    div.textContent = text;
    return div.innerHTML;
  }
})();

function getItem(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var isOk = Math.random() > .01;
    setTimeout(isOk ? resolve : reject, Math.random() * 100, isOk ? id : "?");
  });
}

function getItem(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var section = document.querySelector(".original");
    var div = section.children[id];

    if (!div) {
      section.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<div></div>".repeat(id - section.children.length + 1));
      div = section.children[id];
    }

    div.style.background = 'yellow';

    setTimeout(Math.random() > .1
      ? () => { resolve(id);   div.textContent = id;    div.style.background = 'green'; }
      : () => { reject("?");   div.textContent = "?";   div.style.background = 'red';   },
      Math.random() * 1000
    )
  });
}

async function showAll(ids) {
  var res = await sequence(ids.map(id => () => getItem(id)), 5);

  document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = res.map(({result, error}) => `
    <div style="background:${error ? 'red' : 'green'}">${escapeHTML(error || result)}</div>
  `).join("");
}

showAll(Array(100).fill().map((x, i) => i))
```

```css
section {
  overflow: hidden;
}

section > div {
  height: 1em;
  width: 3ch;
  float: left;
  margin: .125em;
  background: silver;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="original"></section>
<hr>
<section class="result"></section>
```