# Организация очереди запросов к API постороннего ресурса (Node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как правильно организовать очередь запросов? Суть такова: клиент отправляет серверу GET/POST запросы, в соответствии с этим, сервер начинает выполнять API запросы к ресурсу, чтобы потом полученный результат отправить обратно клиенту. Проблема в том, что количество API-запросов за единицу времени этого ресурса ограниченно и чтобы клиенту самому не приходилось угадывать время свободного окна для запроса и сидеть-жать на кнопку, нужно как-то все это поместить в очередь правильно...

Проблема еще в том, что эти API-запросы вложенные, бывает 3-5 уровня вложенности, поэтому это еще сильнее усложняет задачу. На ум ничего не приходит, кроме своей реализации с помощью каких-нибудь таймеров и списка запросов, который будет пополняться до определенного размера, а после выполнения запроса - удалять его. А т.к. Node работает в асинхронном режиме, то как будет себя вести вставка и удаление в общую очередь, когда клиенты одновременно обратятся к запросам - тоже не совсем для меня ясно... Возможно, придется и с этим как-то бороться.

Есть ли идеи по этому поводу? Или же какие-то готовые и удобные решения? Я Node только начал изучать, мало что знаю.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/979103/178988 - оно?

Comment: Во время нового запроса вычисляй время предыдущего и выставляй таймер поспать на разницу во времени

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону [Kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue), плюс небольшой [пример](http://jem-space.ru/riesursoiemkii-node-js-chast-2/).

> Kue - это приоритетная очередь задач, поддерживаемая redis,
> построенная для node.js.
>
> — Kue Team

Redis - широкоиспользуемое и многофункциональное хранилище данных в памяти.

Kue обеспечивает надежную очередь с приоритетми, используя структуру raw/value для Redis.

Основные фичи:

1. Отложенные задания
2. Распараллеливание рабочей нагрузки